# SQL Server Merge Statement compilation throw error Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHEN

Tags: t-sql

I have use sql server merge statement and when compiling the my Store procedure then getting this error.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHEN

Please have a look at my code and tell me where i have made the mistake.

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpTenQKData 
(
    Section                 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    LineItem                NVARCHAR(MAX),
    XFundCode               NVARCHAR(MAX),
    StandardDate            NVARCHAR(MAX),
    StandardValue           VARCHAR(MAX),
    ActualProvidedByCompany VARCHAR(MAX)
)  

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TmpTenQKData 
        SELECT col.value('(Section/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')    AS Section
            ,col.value('(LineItem/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')     AS LineItem   
            ,col.value('(XFundCode/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')    AS XFundCode
            ,col.value('(StandardDate/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS StandardDate
            ,col.value('(StandardValue/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS StandardValue
            ,col.value('(ActualProvidedByCompany/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ActualProvidedByCompany
        FROM @BogyXML.nodes('/Root/PeriodicalData') AS tab (col)            
END


BEGIN
    Merge into TblLineItemTemplate as Trg  
    Using #TmpTenQKData as Src
    on UPPER(TRIM(Trg.LineItem))=UPPER(TRIM(Src.LineItem)) AND Trg.TickerID=@TickerID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET 
            Trg.XFundCode=Src.XFundCode,
            Action='U',
            Insertdate=GETDATE();
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Trg THEN   
        INSERT TblLineItemTemplate
        (
            TickerID,
            LineItem,
            XFundCode,
            Action,
            UserID,
            Insertdate
        ) 
        VALUES 
        (
            TRIM(@TickerID),
            TRIM(Src.LineItem),
            TRIM(Src.XFundCode),
            'I',
            @UserID,GETDATE()
        );         
END
```

Please tell me what to change in code. Thanks

Comment: You have a "wayward" `;` in there before `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Trg THEN `.

Comment: It's also `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` and the `INSERT` doesn't have an `INTO` clause.

Comment: i update merge statement but still getting same error.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the latest code and quote line/column numbers from error

Comment: i have shared latest code and update the merge statement which throwing compilation error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.`

Comment: @SudipBhattacharjee that wayward `;` is still in your current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This parses correctly, if it does what you want is another question:

```sql
MERGE INTO TblLineItemTemplate Trg
USING #TmpTenQKData Src ON UPPER(TRIM(Trg.LineItem)) = UPPER(TRIM(Src.LineItem)) --Do you really need UPPER()? Are you using a case sensitive collation?
                        AND Trg.TickerID = @TickerID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET XFundCode = Src.XFundCode,
                                Action = 'U',
                                Insertdate = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (TickerID,
                                LineItem,
                                XFundCode,
                                Action,
                                UserID,
                                Insertdate)
                        VALUES (TRIM(@TickerID), TRIM(Src.LineItem), TRIM(Src.XFundCode), 'I', @UserID, GETDATE());
```